# Knockout click bindings: onClick vs. onClick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the simple code using knockout like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/egkxq2us/14/) and inside I have a function to capitalize the first name:

```
self.capi = function(){
    self.firstName(self.firstName().toUpperCase());
}
```

and this function will be executed when I click the Capi button. But what I am confused here is when I used `data-bind="click: capi"` , it works fine for me. But if I use `data-bind="click: capi()"`, the first name is capitalized no matter if I click the button or not? Can anyone explain for me here what is the difference between  `data-bind="click: capi()"` and `data-bind="click: capi"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically with the way that Knockout processes these bindings they work the same.

Sort of.

Both of them bind a function to the click event, as expected but something different happens when you stick those `()` on the end. That tells Knockout to not only run it when it's clicked but also go ahead and run it immediately while it's processing it. This can be useful for setting up initial state such as if you wanted to show your users an example of what happens when the button *is* pressed.

**TL;DR**

They work the same but `data-bind="click: capi()"` is both called on click and when they page is loaded.

Comment: More to the point: the `click` binding expects a function. If you put a function *call* there, it expects that the function *returns* the function for the click.

Comment: @RoyJ I never knew the reasoning before but that makes sense. Thanks for that.